# Use an user defined function for data validation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros, data-validation

I created a named range which is the result of a user definer function.

Let say my rage is named `List` and has three items, if I select three cells and enter `=List` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, I get my three items in the cells... so everything looks fine.

If I try to use the range as a data validation source (as a list), I get the "Source Currently evaluates to an error".

Is this a limitation of Excel? If not what is wrong, and how can I do?

The function:

```
Public Function testarrayreturn() As Variant
    Dim Arr(2) As String
    Arr(0) = "a"
    Arr(1) = "b"
    Arr(2) = "c"

    testarrayreturn = Application.Transpose(Arr)
End Function
```

The named range is defined as `testarrayreturn()`

Comment: Is the range on another worksheet ? Data validation is limited to what is on the same sheet as the validation.

Comment: Do you mean that the function must be on the code of the sheet? When there is no user defined function involved, the range can be anywhere, it works fine…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR it's not possible as described (cf. [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783019/can-i-use-vba-function-to-return-a-dynamic-list-of-acceptable-values-into-exce)).

Long(er) answer: there's a workaround. The user-defined function must return a `Range` not an array of value. So the solution is to use a disposable worksheet to "paste" temporary data.

Since avoiding temporary data is the exact reason for which I wanted to use an UDF, that's too bad, but it can be some use for others.